# Passing a null SAFEARRAY to a CComVariant

Tags: c++, com, atl

I came across what looks like a breaking change in `CComVariant` but I can't find any mention of this on the interwebs.

Up to visual studio 2008 passing a `NULL` `SAFEARRAY` pointer to `CComVariant` would result in an empty variant (`VT_EMPTY`), the constructor looked like this:

```
CComVariant(__in_opt const SAFEARRAY *pSrc)
{
    LPSAFEARRAY pCopy;
    if (pSrc != NULL)
    { // ...
```

Starting with visual studio 2010 passing a `nullptr` `SAFEARRAY` to `CComVariant` throws an exception by default. If [`_ATL_NO_VARIANT_THROW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee956430.aspx) is defined it leaves the `CComVariant` in error state (`VT_ERROR`). The constructor starts like this:

```
CComVariant(_In_ const SAFEARRAY *pSrc) ATLVARIANT_THROW()
{
    ATLASSERT(pSrc != NULL);
```

Is there any documentation of the parameter changing from **in-opt** to **in**? Why did Microsoft decide to make such a breaking change? It's very untypical of them to do so.

Comment: [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc1kbba1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), even for 2005, define it as `[in]`. But of course, that doesn't mean anything if the actual implementation did otherwise.

Comment: I suppose that they made a stricter check because `VARIANT` structure with array payload needs to have non-null value. Still a breaking change and you are lucky to have at least assertion failure there.